# Queue of node-horseman calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, node-horseman

I'm developing a web scraper (in its early stages) and I plan to do x horseman calls. This calls are promise based but I want the calls to be sequentially, when one finishes, the next starts.

How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do something like:

```
asyncCall(args[1]).done(() => asyncCall(args[2]))
```

Here `asyncCall` is whatever function you need to call. It takes some arguments and returns a `Promise`.

So you are basically waiting for the result of one call and then invoking the second call.

However, this can get pretty unwieldy when there's a lot of calls to make. If you are using `async/await`, which you should, given that you're working on a new project,  you can code it much better like:

```
await asyncCall(args[1]);
await asyncCall(args[2]);
...
```

Or, even better:

```
for (let arg of args) {
    await asyncCall(arg)
}
```